##[error]No agent found in pool Automation which satisfies the specified demands: maven, Agent.Version -gtVersion 3.243.1
I have created Web Auotmation framework using java , selenium and maven and trying to run the code using azure devops .I have crated the pipleline and also added agent to the agent pool, but I am getting this error while running the piple line.
Any solution or work around
No agent found in pool Automation which satisfies the specified demands: maven, Agent.Version -gtVersion 3.243.1
i am trying to tun pipeline but getting this error.
No agent found in pool Automation which satisfies the specified demands: maven, Agent.Version -gtVersion 3.243.1
tried with connecting the code thru azure repo git and also with the classic editor option and selecting maven to build and run the code.Its giving the error

Please provide more details. Are you using Microsoft or self-hosted build agents? Could you please share which tasks (and versions) are you using in the pipeline?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
